# Visual Studio 2010 ClickOnce prerequisites from same location

Tags: visual-studio-2010, clickonce

I'm using clickonce publishing and want to require .net 3.5 framework and others as prerequisites. I have selected the option to download the prerequisites from same folder as my app. I've also placed the .net 3.5 redistributable exe in the folder on the server where the app will be published. I publish by FTP over the internet to the server where the users are.

However, VS will not let me publish saying it can't find the prerequisites on disk. Does this mean I have to have the prerequisites installed somewhere on my developer machine and that those files will all be uploaded by FTP to the server everytime I publish a new version to the server?

That would be a huge amount of data to upload over my slow DSL upload link.

Any insight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list of prerequisites available for selection depends on the available bootstrapper packages present on the machine where Visual Studio is installed. The Visual Studio installation installs a set of default bootstrapper packages and those are the ones you are using.

For Visual Studio 2010 they are installed to the following location:

`%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages`

When you configure the application prerequisites you can set the download location to the same folder as the application. However not all boostrapper packages support this option and that's why you get the error message. for example, the .NET 3.5 SP1 boostrapper package by default only supports the option to be downloadable from the component vendor's web site.

To workaround this you can follow the instructions in [How to Include .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 with Your Installer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2008/11/18/how-to-include-net-framework-3-5-sp1-with-your-installer.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0).

Also note that since the prerequisites installers will probably not change between your application versions, you can skip the installers when uploading new versions allowing you to save some bandwidth.

Comment: Do I have to do something to skip the installers when uploading new versions? If I leave the prerequisites checked, will they be reuploaded every time?

Comment: I would consider publishing to a local directory and then upload to the server using a FTP client. This way you have total control in which files you want to transfer from your machine allowing you to skip unchanged installers and reusing the ones you already have on the server.